# How do you display only a certain amount of Facebook comments and hide the rest using the Facebook API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, html, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook Comments API on my website. This is what I included in the index file, as outlined in the instructions on the Facebook Devs page here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=123456789";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and on my comments page, I included this line:

```
<ol class="comment-list">
    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>" data-width="470"></div>
    </ol>
```

On the Facebook Devs page, I filled out the information in the box and specified that I only wanted to display 5 comments, then hide the rest. I clicked the confirm button and it spit out the code for me to copy/paste. However, when I used it and tested it on my website, it's displaying 9 comments and hiding the rest. Is there any way to hard code this?

Is something like this possible?

```
<ol class="comment-list">
    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>" data-width="470" data-display_num_comments="5"></div>
    </ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to hard code the number of comments to show, use the `num_posts` attribute, like this:

```
<ol class="comment-list">
   <div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"
        data-width="470" data-num_posts="5" ></div>
</ol>
```

Note that you have to prepend it with `data-`